# Hourglass code logic error using nested for loops

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm working on a assignment where I need to print our an hourglass using nested for loops. The input base number(number of initial quotation marks) is user inputed, and odd and even difference is that there is a colon in the middle.
I'm currently working on UpCone, haven't even started on the mess of downcone, I need help because I can't find the logic error as to why colon # is printing MORE than I want, even after adjusting baseVal by subtracting 2
My code:

```
`public class HourglassProject {
    /*
     * Print Base
     * Print Middle
     * Print invPyrimid
     * Print Pyrimid
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the length of the base(# of colons), reccomended 10/12");
        int numLength = userInput.nextInt();
        printBase(numLength);
        upCone(numLength);

        
        userInput.close();
    }
    
    public static void printBase(int baseNum) {
        String quotation = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < baseNum; i++) {
            quotation += "\"";
        }
        System.out.println("|"+ quotation +"|");
        
    }
**  public static void upCone(int baseVal) {
        int lineNum = 0; 
        String colon= "";
        String space = "";
        //for loops: Line, Spaces; Colon shrink
        while(baseVal > 0) {
            
            for(int i = 0; i <= lineNum; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                
                for(int j = 1; j <= (baseVal - 2); j++) {
                    colon += ":";
                
                }
                baseVal -= 2;
            }
            lineNum++;
            System.out.println("\\" + colon + "/");
            colon = "";
        }**
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= lineNum; i++) {
            space += " ";
        }
        
        if(baseVal % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(space + "||");
            
        } else {
            System.out.println(space + "|:|");
        }
        
        
    }`

Desired: 
|””””””””””|
 \::::::::/
  \::::::/
   \::::/
    \::/
     ||
    /::\
   /::::\
  /::::::\
 /::::::::\
|””””””””””|


What I have: 
enter the length of the base(# of colons), reccomended 10/12
10
|""""""""""|
 \::::::::/
  \::::::::::/
   \::/
    ||
```

Comment: Check how your loops are nested, particularly where you put together the colons. Also, you should not be closing the Scanner, since it is wrapping System.in, something which you did not open.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes help to just read through your code and step through it like a naive execution would. Or if you are already familiar with a debugger you could step through your code line by line while watching the variables change.
Doing this you should notice an issue with this part of your code:

```
while(baseVal > 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= lineNum; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        
        for(int j = 1; j <= (baseVal - 2); j++) {
            colon += ":";
        
        }
        baseVal -= 2;
    }
    lineNum++;
    System.out.println("\\" + colon + "/");
    colon = "";
}
```

Specifically look what the outer `for` loop is doing with each iteration of the outmost `while` (especially after the first iteration). Track how `lineNum` is changing and what it means for `baseVal` and `colon`

Answer (score 1):

Your second for loop shouldn't be nested inside the previous:

```
    while(baseVal > 0) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= lineNum; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }    
        for(int j = 1; j <= (baseVal - 2); j++) {
            colon += ":";
            
        }
        baseVal -= 2;
```

This should fix it i think :)
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I'm working on a assignment where I need to print our an hourglass using nested for loops. ..."*

Great attempt.  I don't see the practicality in using the nested *loop*.

Utilize the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* and *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class to format the value.

```java
class Hourglass {
    int w, h;

    Hourglass(int n) {
        h = (w = n) / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter f = new Formatter(s);
        f.format("|%s|%n", "”".repeat(w));
        for (int i = 1; i < h; i++)
            f.format("%s\\%s/%n", " ".repeat(i), ":".repeat(w - (i * 2)));
        f.format("%s%s%n", " ".repeat(h), w % 2 != 0 ? "|||" : "||");
        for (int i = h - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            f.format("%s/%s\\%n", " ".repeat(i), ":".repeat(w - (i * 2)));
        f.format("|%s|", "”".repeat(w));
        f.flush();
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

Output

```
|””””””””””|
 \::::::::/
  \::::::/
   \::::/
    \::/
     ||
    /::\
   /::::\
  /::::::\
 /::::::::\
|””””””””””|
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it more challenging by sweeping from top to bottom in just one outer for loop, and sweeping left to right with just one nested for loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Hourglass width? ");
    int width = sc.nextInt();
        
    int left = 1;
    int right = width+2;
    int lastRow = width+((width%2==0) ? 1 : 2);
    for(int row=1; row<=lastRow;row++) {
      for(int col=1; col<=width+2; col++) {
        if (row==1 || row==lastRow) {
          System.out.print((col==1 || col==width+2) ? "|" : "\"");
        } 
        else if (col<left || col>right) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        else if(right-left<=1) {
          System.out.print("|");
        }
        else if (col==left) {
          System.out.print((row<=((width+1)/2)) ? "\\" : "/");
        }
        else if (col==right) {
          System.out.print((row<=((width+1)/2)) ? "/" : "\\");
        }
        else {
          System.out.print(":");
        }
      } 
      System.out.println();
      left += (row<(width+1)/2+1) ? 1 : -1;
      right += (row<(width+1)/2+1) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Sample runs:

```
Hourglass width? 25
|"""""""""""""""""""""""""|
 \:::::::::::::::::::::::/ 
  \:::::::::::::::::::::/  
   \:::::::::::::::::::/   
    \:::::::::::::::::/    
     \:::::::::::::::/     
      \:::::::::::::/      
       \:::::::::::/       
        \:::::::::/        
         \:::::::/         
          \:::::/          
           \:::/           
            \:/            
             |             
            /:\            
           /:::\           
          /:::::\          
         /:::::::\         
        /:::::::::\        
       /:::::::::::\       
      /:::::::::::::\      
     /:::::::::::::::\     
    /:::::::::::::::::\    
   /:::::::::::::::::::\   
  /:::::::::::::::::::::\  
 /:::::::::::::::::::::::\ 
|"""""""""""""""""""""""""|

Hourglass width? 24
|""""""""""""""""""""""""|
 \::::::::::::::::::::::/ 
  \::::::::::::::::::::/  
   \::::::::::::::::::/   
    \::::::::::::::::/    
     \::::::::::::::/     
      \::::::::::::/      
       \::::::::::/       
        \::::::::/        
         \::::::/         
          \::::/          
           \::/           
            ||            
           /::\           
          /::::\          
         /::::::\         
        /::::::::\        
       /::::::::::\       
      /::::::::::::\      
     /::::::::::::::\     
    /::::::::::::::::\    
   /::::::::::::::::::\   
  /::::::::::::::::::::\  
 /::::::::::::::::::::::\ 
|""""""""""""""""""""""""|
```